# after catching "InterruptedException", why "Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()"'s value is false?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

as the title.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());   //print false, who reset the interrupt?

            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    thread.interrupt();
}
```

after catching "InterruptedException", why "Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()"'s value is false?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the Javadoc for [`Thread.sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) (called by `TimeUnit.sleep`):

> InterruptedException - if any thread has interrupted the current thread. The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.

I think the intention of `isInterrupted()` is to allow you to detect whether a thread has been interrupted *before* calling something which would throw `InterruptedException`. If you've *caught* `InterruptedException`, it's fair to assume that the thread *has* been interrupted...

Comment: +1: If your thread is interrupted again, after throwing an exception but before you check it, it will be `true`