# Bound Thread running time

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I'm trying to find more information on how to bound the running time of a task created using [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

I want to create a self destructing, e.g. when time has passed (1m for example) then the thread will terminate itself automatically and return a null value. The key point here is that waiting for the thread to finish should not block the main thread (UI thread in our example).

I know I can use the [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#get%28%29) method, however it will block my application.

I was thinking about running an additional internal thread that will sleep for 1m and then will call interrupt on the main thread.

I attached an example code, it looks like a good idea, but I need another pair of eyes telling me if it makes sense.

```
public abstract class AbstractTask<T> implements Callable<T> {
private final class StopRunningThread implements Runnable {
    /**
     * Holds the main thread to interrupt. Cannot be null.
     */
    private final Thread mMain;

    public StopRunningThread(final Thread main) {
        mMain = main;

    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
            // Stop it.
            mMain.interrupt();
        } catch (final InterruptedException exception) {
            // Ignore.
        }
    }
}
```

call() is called via a ThreadPool

```
public T call() {
    try {
        // Before running any task initialize the result so that the user
        // won't
        // think he/she has something.
        mResult = null;
        mException = null;
        // Stop running thread.
        mStopThread = new Thread(new StopRunningThread(
                Thread.currentThread()));
        mStopThread.start();

        mResult = execute(); <-- A subclass implements this one
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        // An error occurred, ignore any result.
        mResult = null;
        mException = e;
        // Log it.
        Ln.e(e);
    }
    // In case it's out of memory do a special catch.
    catch (final OutOfMemoryError e) {
        // An error occurred, ignore any result.
        mResult = null;
        mException = new UncheckedException(e);
        // Log it.
        Ln.e(e);
    } finally {
        // Stop counting.
        mStopThread.interrupt();
    }

    return mResult;
}
```

There are couple of points which I'm afraid of:

- What will happen if execute() has an exception and immediately afterwards my external thread will interrupt, then I'll never catch the exception.
- Memory/CPU consumption, I am using a thread pool to avoid the creation of new threads.

Do you see a better idea for reaching the same functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this would be somewhat involved.  First, you'd need to extend the ThreadPoolExecutor class.  You'll need to override the "beforeExecute" and "afterExecute" methods.  They would keep track of thread start times, and do cleanup after.  Then you'd need a reaper to periodically check to see which threads need cleaning up.

This example uses a Map to record when each thread is started.  The beforeExecute method populates this, and the afterExecute method cleans it up.  There is a TimerTask which periodically executes and looks at all the current entries (ie. all the running threads), and calls Thread.interrupt() on all of them that have exceeded the given time limit.

Notice that I have given two extra constructor parameters:  maxExecutionTime, and reaperInterval to control how long tasks are given, and how often to check for tasks to kill.  I've omitted some constructors here for the the sake of brevity.

Keep in mind the tasks you submit have to play nice and allow themselves to be killed.  This means you have to:

1. Check Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() at regular intervals
   during execution.
2. Try to avoid any blocking operation that does not declare
   InterruptedException in it's throws clause.  A prime example of this
   would be InputStream/OutputStream usage, and you would use NIO
   Channels instead.  If you have to use these methods, check the interrupted flag immediately after returning from such an operation.

.

```
public class TimedThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    private Map<Thread, Long> threads = new HashMap<Thread, Long>();
    private Timer timer;

    public TimedThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize,
            long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
            long maxExecutionTime,
            long reaperInterval) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
        startReaper(maxExecutionTime, reaperInterval);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        threads.remove(Thread.currentThread());
        System.out.println("after: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        super.beforeExecute(t, r);
        System.out.println("before: " + t.getName());
        threads.put(t, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

@Override
protected void terminated() {
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    super.terminated();
}

    private void startReaper(final long maxExecutionTime, long reaperInterval) {
        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // make a copy to avoid concurrency issues.
                List<Map.Entry<Thread, Long>> entries = 
                        new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Thread, Long>>(threads.entrySet());
                for (Map.Entry<Thread, Long> entry : entries) {
                    Thread thread = entry.getKey();
                    long start = entry.getValue();
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start > maxExecutionTime) {
                        System.out.println("interrupting thread : " + thread.getName());
                        thread.interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }

        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, reaperInterval, reaperInterval);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        TimedThreadPoolExecutor executor = new TimedThreadPoolExecutor(5,5, 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(20),
                1000L,
                200L);

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000L);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        while (! executor.isTerminated()) {
            executor.awaitTermination(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: note of course that all tasks submitted to this pool have the same timeout.  However, there's only 1 extra thread created (which doesn't do a whole lot), and from a user perspective, they still see only an ExecutorService.  They don't have to alter the Callable they are submitting.

Comment: Looks like a great solution. Regarding your comments at the end, from the javadoc I can see that isInterrupted() is [cleared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901649/after-catching-interruptedexception-why-thread-currentthread-isinterrupted) when an exception is thrown, so checking it won't be really helpful, am I right ?

Comment: Another quick question, what happens to a thread in a thread pool that gets interrupted ? I couldn't see anything in Java source code that handles interrupted threads

Comment: Then you check Thread.isInterrupted(), you should most likely just throw an InterruptedException out of your code.  However, since the "run()" method doesn't allow that, you might have to wrap it in a RuntimeException, or log it, and just immediately return.  When a thread in a threadpool gets interrupted, it depends on how you're using it.  In general, threads will interrupt silently.  However, if you throw an exception from the run() method, the Future object from your submission (assuming you used a callable, and not a Runnable) will throw an ExecutionException when you call the get method.

Comment: Also, I think if you're really interested in knowing when things are auto terminated, you should build a Listener into the above class, and send of messages to interested parties after you call Thread.interrupt().  This might cause you the rethink the contents of your map so that you can get the Runnable that's in a particular thread, or you could just pass the Thread itself off to the listener.