# Interrupted exception vs isInterrupted in a while loop

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, while-loop, interrupted-exception

Assume that I have the following code:

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){  
    //do something   
    Thread.sleep(5000);  
}
```

Now `Thread.sleep` throws `InterruptedException so it should be like this:

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){  
   //do something   
   try{  
     Thread.sleep(5000);    
   } catch(InterruptedException e){  

   }
}
```

If I hit the `catch` will the `while` loop continue or do I need to do `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`? If I do call this method, won't that also cause an `InterruptedException`? Otherwise how I got the exception in the first place?

Also if I have:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){  
   //do something   
   callMethod();  
}  

private void callMethod(){  
   //do something  
   try {  
     Thread.sleep(5000);    
   } catch(InterruptedException e){  

   }
}
```

again will my `while` loop break?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901649/after-catching-interruptedexception-why-thread-currentthread-isinterrupted

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024651/do-i-have-to-worry-about-interruptedexceptions-if-i-dont-interrupt-anything-mys

Comment: You should read the [Law of the sabotaged doorbell](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue146.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your question is more about `try - catch - finally`  than about multithreading.

1) If `sleep` throws an `Exception`, the `catch` block will execute and then the `while` loop continues.

2) You do the exact same thing as in 1)

To leave the `while` loop, do:

```
try{  
   while(!Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted){  
       //do something   
       Thread.sleep(5000);    
   }  
}
catch(InterruptedException e){  

}
```

In that case, if an `Exception` is thrown, the `while` loop is left and the `catch` block is executed.

Comment: +1: however I prefer to catch Exceptions inside the loop and then break or continue explicitly.

Comment: @BigMike Yes, that approach is completely in line with the Java maxim "More code means better code".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik it's just that I don't want to use a catch block to control my program flow, if I need to exit from a loop, I want to be the one stating that with an explicit break, and that justfor the sake of who'll inherit my code tomorrow...

Comment: @BigMike In other words, you'd prefer a language that doesn't have the exceptions mechanism. Exceptions control the flow whether you like it or not; you just make them control the flow in a way that involves more code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik maybe you're right, I guess as usual it depends on personal taste and scenarios. Btw, I honestly hate java, still in love with good old C ;)

Comment: @BigMike Exceptions are often a blessing as well---what if an interrupt signal needs to break out of a 10-level deep call stack? You'd need **a lot** of boilerplate code to handle that without exceptions and the end result would in no way be more comprehensible or maintainable.

Comment: @Vakimshaar:So in the second case I should do:`Thread.currentThread.interrupt()` so that when `callMethod()` returns the `while` loop breaks?

Comment: @Jim In your 2nd case, you should place the ``try - catch`` block around the ``callMethod()``

Comment: @Vakimshaar:Why?If I do the `try-catch` inside the `callMethod()` and in the `catch` I do `Thread.currentThread.interrupt()` won't the loop break?

Answer (score 2):

Calling interrupt on a thread does not in itself throw an exception. Sleeping or waiting while the interrupt flag is set is what causes InterruptedException to be thrown.

It is totally predictable what can throw InterruptedException, so that the thread being interrupted has control and it can choose how to respond. It's a checked exception so it's evident what throws it. It is not like ThreadDeath, which can be thrown anywhere.

When an InterruptedException is thrown the thread's interrupted status is reset. If you want to restore the thread's interrupted status, because you want to check the flag later and have it be true, call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` in order to set it.

Nothing out of the ordinary happens during interruption to change how  instructions get processed. So if you choose to catch the InterruptedException in a loop and check the flag to get out, you will need to reset the flag:

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){  
   //do something   
   try{  
     Thread.sleep(5000);    
   } catch(InterruptedException e){  
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
}
```

Alternatively you can use the InterruptedException to get out of the loop:

```
try {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        // do something
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // flag value is not used here, but still good style
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
}
```

If this last snippet is the whole run method of the thread being interrupted, you can get by without setting the interrupted status again, but if you have components being used by other parts you don't want one badly-behaved part to squelch the interrupted flag so that other code in the thread is not aware of the interruption.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.sleep()` will clear the "interrupted status" before throwing `InterruptedException`. You need to call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` in the catch block, otherwise the while condition will most likely not  succeed, because the thread will always be "not interrupted" when `callMethod` returns.

The exception is not caused by the `interrupt()` method, but by `sleep()` blocking on a thread that has been signaled as "interrupted". This is explained in more detail [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906799/why-invoke-thread-currentthread-interrupt-when-catch-any-interruptexception).